# Read ruby syntax in java

Tags: java, ruby, vagrant, velocity

I have a tool backed by Velocity templates which statically creates a file (Ruby like syntax) after capturing inputs from Web App for use with some other tool (Vagrant - built in Ruby). However, now I wish to support the reverse of what is being done till now so that I can browse a previously created Vagrant file in my tool and have the settings defined there-in populate my Java Beans and end up at the Web App's UI.

Is there any way to interpret the Ruby Syntax like:

```
config.vm.define :firstMachine do |master|
        master.vm.hostname = "boxupp.test.first"
        master.vm.box = "Ubuntu"
        master.vm.box_url = "http://www.google.com"


        master.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |prov|
            prov.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "384"]
        end
end
```

and populate the corresponding values in the Java Beans.

I stumbled across JRuby but it looks like another Scripting platform.

Thanks for your time !!

Comment: Jruby is just ruby - with the added benefit it can easily call java code because it is written on top of java.  It sounds like you want to call ruby from java (if I understand your question correctly)?

Comment: Thanks Chris ! I just want to interpret Ruby code in Java and populate the Java beans ultimately. I think there must be something built into JRuby that could interpret the Ruby Syntax

Comment: Jruby *is* a ruby interpreter, so yes it interprets ruby :) can you provide some details on the java side of things that you're looking for it to interact with?

Comment: [Using the JRuby Interpreter from Java](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JavaIntegration#wiki-Using_the_JRuby_Interpreter_from_Java)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to read / parse the syntax, then you would need to write (or find) a Ruby parser written in Java.

If you mean interpret ... as in execute / run ... Ruby code in Java, then you either need:

- a Ruby interpreter that you can call from Java; see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/JRubyAndJavaCodeExamples
- or a way to turn Ruby code into a real Java method; see https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/GeneratingJavaClasses

---

> I stumbled across JRuby but it looks like another Scripting platform.

Ermm ... it is an implementation of the Ruby language.